# Регулярное выражение: в строку входит хотя бы одна буква кириллицы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение, которое проверяет, что в строку входит хотя бы одна буква кириллицы.
Остальные символы могут быть любыми.

Comment: `/[а-яё]/` с модификатором регистронезависимости

Comment: это не работает

Comment: думаете? а то мне кажется, что не работает код, в котором вы пытаетесь применить это выражение, а не само выражение. Но вы, видимо, не считаете нужным его добавить в вопрос

Comment: В вакууме это не будет работать... Какой язык программирования используется? Каким образом Вы пробовали? Приведите, пожалуйста, рабочий пример кода (`Ctrl + M` в редакторе).

Comment: VisualStudio, c# во всех файлах проекта (Ctrl+Shift+F) нужно найти текстовые строки ("...ю..."), которые содержат хотя-бы одну русскую букву. Прошу прощения, что не указал это подробно в самом вопросе.

Comment: ".*[а-яА-ЯёЁ].*" - работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex, оформление регулярного выражения в разных языках может отличаться, в том же JavaScript именно слэши `/` чаще применяются как особый литерал для регулярки (альтернатива - более многословное создание объекта `new RegExp("regexp"[, "flags"])`)

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое выражение: `/.*\p{Cyrillic}.*/` -- буквально проверяет наличие хотя бы одного символа *кириллицы*, [онлайн демо](https://regex101.com/r/DEqu4f/1).

Если нужно ограничиться только современным русским алфавитом, вместо Unicode-класса `Cyrillic` можно указать символы из соответствующего диапазона:
`/.*[А-ЯЁа-яё].*/`.

Comment: `.*` не нужны. Достаточно `/\p{Cyrillic}/`.

Comment: Смотря как вызывать такое выражение, если для аналога `String::matches` в Java, то `.*` понадобятся.